# react-particles-js not working on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, particles.js

I am using react-particles.js npm package on Next.js project.
It is working well on developer mode but it's not working on production mode.

The code is below

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Particle Demo</title>
      </Head>
      <Particles />
    </div>
  )
}
```

There is no error on console both developer and production mode.

Comment: _"it's not working on production mode"_ - Could you please be more specific? What's not working?

Comment: I can see the particles on dev mode but when it's build and run it, I can't see any particles.

Comment: I have the same problem :( Do you remember how you fixed it?

Comment: you can use ts-particles package instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ts-particles` npm package instead.
It should works fine